# SDL Web8.5 : CME not loading due to SHA-1 Certificate issue

Tags: web8

I just upgrade SDL Web8.1 to SDL Web8.5, CME loading and CME Content Explorer not loading. Please let me know the configuration/setup issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your Certificate rather than with the CME.

Comment: CME loading and Content Explorer not load..

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: 100 times cleared broswer cache.!!!

Comment: Try using a different browser (or did you already try 100 different ones? ;-)

Comment: Given this is a standard Firefox warning, I doubt that this is what's stopping the CME from loading. You will get this warning with a different version of Tridion anyway, if you use the same certificate. I think the reason why the CME doesn't load is related to something else - like extensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iis configuration issue and updated correct Certificate and working fine.